# Compiler options for C# project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

Where I can change compiler options for C# project in VisualStudio 2008 (without command prompt). I need it to turn off optimization to compare optimized IL-code and unoptimized IL-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Right Click the Project] -> Properties -> Build -> Optimize Code

Answer (score 2):

Project Properties => Build => Uncheck Optimize code

Answer (score 0):

And just as info: If you run in the debugger you will always get completely unoptimized execution. Regardless of the settings.

Comment: That is not true.  If you optimize, some lines may not execute, such as unused local variables and etc...