# Compiler options for C# projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xml-documentation, compiler-options

I can't seem to find where to put compiler options (specifically /doc) for my project. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310236/visual-c-sharp-compiler-options) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579590/compiler-options-for-c-sharp-project) both say they are in Project > Properties > Build tab, but I do not see any build tab (see below). I can only assume this was changed sometime between VS2010 and VS2013. There is a build events tab, but I'm not sure if that's the same thing, and there are two text boxes, one for pre-build and one for post-build. Where do I put compiler arguments? Is there a better way to make the project output an xml documentation file?

[image]

Comment: When I create a new Console app I get a build tab.

Comment: @HansPassant I've also noticed this on my install of VS2015 pre-release, and I thought it might have been a feature that wasn't yet implemented. Will I need to re-install each and every extension I've ever used, including the ones from external programs like Paradox and Qt?

Comment: Before you try re-installing VS, are you running post sharp? According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646881/the-build-tab-missing-from-project-properties-in-visual-studio-2013 that could be your problem

Comment: Why the downvote? Some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [David Arno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7122/david-arno), this seems to be a [problem with PostSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646881/the-build-tab-missing-from-project-properties-in-visual-studio-2013). Uninstalling that extension fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, that this issue is based on Post Sharp.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (german version) and after updating PostSharp to Version 4.1.14 the "Build" and the "Postsharp" Tab disapears.

Uninstalling PostSharp fixed this issue. The "Build" Tab is back again.